# Json_encode как передать массив

Tags: php, json_encode

есть строка вида "1, 230 цех асу, 0" почему json_encode кодирует следущим видом "1, 230 , 0" и как это побороть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кстати, кириллица была виновата сделал что то вроде

```
    "text"  => iconv("Windows-1251", "UTF-8",ereg_replace("\"","",$row[1])),
```

Answer (score 0):

А чего вы ожидаете? Строка в формате JSON выглядит именно так.
Вы передаете строку и получаете, соответственно, строку.
Передавайте в json_encode массив, получите массив.

```
json_encode(explode(', ', '1, 230 цех асу, 0'), true);
// ["1","230 цех асу","0"]
```

Comment: я так понимаю, вопрос в исчезновении кириллицы